# C# API to test if a network Adapter is firewalled

Tags: c#, networking, adapter, windows-firewall

Given - 
.Net 2.0
XP machine with SP2 and 
multiple network adapters

Is there an API that can be used to check if the network adapter is firewalled?

OneGuyInDC

Answer (score 6):

Give this c# code below a go. It works for Windows 7 (& Vista) and XP.
This will get the status of, and enable/disable the Windows firewall for the current profile, eg: Home/Domain/Public access networks.

**Usage:**

```
getFirewallStatus() 
  --> returns true/false for whether the windows firewall is enable/disabled.

setFirewallStatus(newStatus) 
  --> sets the firewall enabled/disabled to the true/false value passed in
      eg, to enable the firewall:
         setFirewallStatus(true)

getCurrPolicy()  
  --> used by the other two methods

isWinXP()
  --> returns whether windows version is WinXP/2000 or newer, ie: Vista/Win7
      used by the other methods to determine which code to use.
```

**Code:**

```
using NetFwTypeLib; 
// (don't forget to add it to your references, its under the COM tab)

public bool isWinXP()
{
   OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
   int majorVersion = os.Version.Major;
   // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx
   if (majorVersion < 6) // if O/S is not Vista or Windows7
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}
private static INetFwPolicy2 getCurrPolicy()
{
    INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2;
    Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
    fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
    return fwPolicy2;
}
public bool getFirewallStatus()
{
    bool result = false;
    switch (isWinXP())
    {
        case true:
            Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
            INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
            result = mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;
            break;
        case false:
            INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = getCurrPolicy();
            NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_ fwCurrentProfileTypes;
            //read Current Profile Types (only to increase Performace)
            //avoids access on CurrentProfileTypes from each Property
            fwCurrentProfileTypes = (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_)fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
            result = (fwPolicy2.get_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes));
            break;
        default:
            result = false; // assume Win7 by default
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
public void setFirewallStatus(bool newStatus)
{
    switch (isWinXP())
    {
        case true:
            Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false);
            INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
            mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled = newStatus;
            break;
        case false:
            NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_ fwCurrentProfileTypes;
            INetFwPolicy2 currPolicy = getCurrPolicy();
            //read Current Profile Types (only to increase Performace)
            //avoids access on CurrentProfileTypes from each Property
            fwCurrentProfileTypes = (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_)currPolicy.CurrentProfileTypes;
            currPolicy.set_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes, newStatus);
            break;
        default:
            NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_ fwCurrentProfileTypes1;
            INetFwPolicy2 currPolicy1 = getCurrPolicy();
            //read Current Profile Types (only to increase Performace)
            //avoids access on CurrentProfileTypes from each Property
            fwCurrentProfileTypes1 = (NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_)currPolicy1.CurrentProfileTypes;
            currPolicy1.set_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes1, newStatus);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to know *in general* (e.g. if there is an external firewall) for the following reasons:

1. If you aren't receiving incoming connections, your external interface may just be down.
2. If you are unable to make outgoing connections, your external interface may just be down.

But there *is* an API for finding out if the Windows Firewall is enabled on a given network interface.  You will need to use COM interop to get the INetFwProfile (for global firewall status) and INetSharingConfiguration (for a specific network interface) interfaces, and check INetFwProfile.FirewallEnabled and INetSharingConfiguration.InternetFirewallEnabled.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364717%28VS.85%29.aspx for links and for how to use these results to determine the effective firewall status.  (It's written in terms of VBScript but should be translatable to C#.)